# Proving that there exists $\leq 1$ pairs in the sequence $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{n}{a_n}$ whose sum is a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The infinite sequence of positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots$ satisfies $1 < a_1 < 2$ as well as $$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{n}{a_n}$$
for all positive integers $n.$ Prove that there exists at most one pair of distinct terms of this sequence whose sum is a positive integer.

---

Since the problem asks for a proof that there exists at most one pair, I thought a proof by contradiction would be a good way to proceed with the problem. However, after testing a couple of terms, I was unable to find a clear relationship that would help me establish that there could not exist more than one pair of distinct terms that satisfy the given condition.

Comment: Hint: Use induction to show that if $n<a_n<n+\delta$ than $n+1<a_{n+1}<n+1+\delta$. Also, notice that the fraction part of $a_2$ is smaller than $0.5$.

Comment: @JetfiRex: I think you should make it into an answer.

Comment: Yep. That's what I came up with. See my answer for too many details.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$a_{n+1}
=a_n+\dfrac{n}{a_n}$
where $1 < a_1=a < 2$.

Let
$a_n
=n+b_n$.
I will show that
$0 < b_n < 1$
and
$b_{n+1} < b_n$.
This implies that,
if $m > n$,
and $b_n \le \frac12$
then
$0 < \{ a_m+a_n \} < 1
$
so the sum can
never be an integer.
Therefore
the only solutions are
$a_1+a_m$
for $m > 1$
for a  particular value of $a_1$.

Note:
These results can also be used
to show that
$a_n-a_m$ is never an integer for
$n > m$.

I will also show that
$b_n \to 0$.

Note:
All calculations were done with
Wolfram Alpha.

Letting
$a_n
=n+b_n$,
$n+1+b_{n+1}
=n+b_n+\dfrac{n}{n+b_n}
=n+b_n+1-\dfrac{b_n}{n+b_n}
$
so,
if $0 < b_n < 1$
(which is true for $n=1$),
$b_{n+1}
=b_n-\dfrac{b_n}{n+b_n}
=b_n(1-\dfrac{1}{n+b_n})
\lt b_n
$
and
$b_{n+1} > 0$.

Since $b_n$ is
a bounded decreasing sequence,
it has a limit.
$b_{n+1}
=b_n(1-\dfrac{1}{n+b_n})
\lt b_n(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1})
= b_n\dfrac{n}{n+1}
$
so
$\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}
\lt\dfrac{n}{n+1}
$.

Therefore,
if $m > n$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{b_m}{b_n}
&=\prod_{k=n}^{m-1} \dfrac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}\\
&<\prod_{k=n}^{m-1} \dfrac{k}{k+1}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{m}\\
\text{so}\\
b_m
&<\dfrac{nb_n}{m}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Here is a proof
of the behavior
of the fractional part
of $a_n$.

If $0 < b_n < 1$,
which is true for
$n=1$,
then
$b_{n+1} < b_n$
and
$b_{n+1}
\gt b_n(1-\dfrac{1}{n})
\gt 0$.

Therefore,
if $m > n$ then
$a_m+a_n
=m+b_m+(n+b_n)
=(m+n)+(b_n+b_m)
$.
Since
$0 < b_m < b_n < 1$,
$0 < b_n+b_m < 2$,
so
$a_m+a_n$
is only an integer
when
$b_n+b+m=1$.

Now,
a discussion of the
cases when
$a_n+a_m$
is an integer.

Since
$1 < a_1 < 2$,
$0 < a_1-1 < 1$
so $0 < b_1 < 1$.

Regarding $a_2$,
if
$f(a)
=a+\dfrac1{a}
$,
$f'(a)
=1-\dfrac1{a^2}
\gt 0
$
for
$1 < a < 2$.
$f(1)=2,
f(2)=\dfrac52
$
so
$0 < b_2 < \dfrac12$.

Therefore the only possible cases
where $a_m+a_n$ is an integer
with $m > n$
have $n=1$.

Since the fractional part
of $a_1$ is any value
from $0$ to $1$,
there is always a solution to
$a_m+a_1$ being an integer.

Here are the solutions for
$m=2, 3, 4$.

If
$b_1+b_2 = 1$
then
$1
= a+a+\dfrac1{a}-3
= 2a+\dfrac1{a}-3
$
which has roots
$1 \pm \dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}
$.
So the only solution with
$1 < a < 2$ is
$a=1 +\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}
$.

Regarding $a_3$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{3}
&=a_2+\dfrac{2}{a_2}\\
&=a+\dfrac1{a}+\dfrac{2}{a+\dfrac1{a}}\\
&=\dfrac{a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1)}\\
&=f(a)\\
f'(a)
&=\dfrac{(a^2 - 1) (a^4 + 1)}{(a^3 + a)^2}\\
&>0
\qquad\text{for } a>1\\
f(1)
&=3\\
f(2)
&=\dfrac{16+16+1}{10}\\
&=\dfrac{33}{10}\\
\end{array}
$

So
$0 < b_3 < \dfrac{3}{10}
$.

If
$b_1+b_3 = 1$
then
$1
= a+\dfrac{a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1)}-4
=\dfrac{(a - 1) (2 a^3 - 2 a^2 + 3 a - 1)}{a (a^2 + 1)}
$.
The only root between
$1$ and $2$ is approximately
$a≈1.79680060800578
$.

Regarding $a_4$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{4}
&=a_3+\dfrac{3}{a_3}\\
&=\dfrac{a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1)}+\dfrac{3}{\dfrac{a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1)}}\\
&=\dfrac{a^8 + 11 a^6 + 24 a^4 + 11 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1) (a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1)}\\
&=f(a)\\
f'(a)
&=\dfrac{(a - 1) (a + 1) (a^4 + 1) (a^8 + 5 a^6 + 12 a^4 + 5 a^2 + 1)}{a^2 (a^2 + 1)^2 (a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1)^2}\\
&>0
\qquad\text{for } a>1\\
f(1)
&=4\\
f(2)
&=\dfrac{463}{110}\\
\end{array}
$

So
$0 < b_4 < \dfrac{23}{110}
$.

If
$b_1+b_4 = 1$
then
$1
= a+\dfrac{a^8 + 11 a^6 + 24 a^4 + 11 a^2 + 1}{a (a^2 + 1) (a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1)}-5\\
=\dfrac{(a - 1) (2 a^7 - 3 a^6 + 13 a^5 - 12 a^4 + 17 a^3 - 8 a^2 + 4 a - 1)}{a (a^2 + 1) (a^4 + 4 a^2 + 1)}
$

and the only real root
of this between
$1$ and $2$
is approximately
$a≈1.8448915281535634816
$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_{n}=a_{n}-n$. Then $0<b_{1}<1$.

We have $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-(n+1)=a_{n}+\frac{n}{a_{n}}-(n+1)=b_{n}+n+\frac{n}{b_{n}+n}-n-1=b_{n}(1-\frac{1}{b_{n}+n})$.

So we have $0<b_{n}<1$.

(Different from the previous answer here)

Noticed that $b_{n+1}-b_{n}=-\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n}+n}<0$, and $b_{2}=b_{1}(1-\frac{1}{b_{1}+1})<1-\frac{1}{b_{1}+1}<1-\frac{1}{1+1}<\frac{1}{2}$.

So we have $...<b_{3}<b_{2}<\frac{1}{2}$.

For intergers $i>j$, if $a_{i}+a_{j}$ is an interger, $b_{i}+b_{j}$ is an interger too.

Because of $0<b_{n}<1$, we have $b_{i}+b_{j}=1$.

So $j=1$.(or $b_{i}+b_{j}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$)

However, ${b_{n}}$ is decreasing, so there exist only one number $i$ such that $b_{i}=1-b_{1}$ at most. Done!